# Convert words from .txt file to an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a game which needs a wordlist called "words.txt" and inside this file, it looks like :

```
zoologie
zozoter
Zurich
zygote
```

And i need to convert it to an Array for VueJS which will look like :

```
export default {
  data(){
     return{
      words: ["zoologie", "zozoter", "Zurich", "Zygote"]
     }
  }
}
```

The problem is that i don't know how to do it, because if i proceed 1by1, it will take a long time (22k words in it)

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "1by1"?

Comment: If i modify the file by myself, and quote them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have node installed, you can do something like this:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let string = `export default {
  data(){
     return{
      words: [`;
fs.readFileSync("words.txt").toString().split("\n").forEach(el => {
  string += `"${el}",`;
});
string += `]
     }
  }
}`;
fs.writeFile("yourfile.js", string);
```

Comment: Fixed. Made other fixes as well. Edit: I've tested it as well, seems to work okay for me

Comment: If my answer worked, feel free to accept it as correct so that other people having the same problem would know where to look